# Will turning multiple divs (which contain .GIF images) invisible reduce the memory used for a page?

Tags: image, html, gif, src

I have a website that features lots of divs. Each div contains a different animated image. Now, as you scroll down more divs with animated images are added.

After a while, a lot of GIFs are on the page at the same time and this will make the page laggy!

My question is, what would be the best method to "tidy" the previously loaded GIFs (which are not in view-port anymore) in order to reduce the "memory load" of the page?

What I have thought about:

- Change the SRC of the IMGs to Thumbnails
- Turn the divs invisible
- Hide the divs and somehow add a dummy margin
- ... ?

Comment: Unless the image is hidden with `display:none` style, it'll affect web page rendering performance. Unless the image element is in the web page, it will consume memory. I'd suggest removing the image elements from the web page to decrease memory and speed up performance.

Comment: @Jay The problem with removing the image elements is, that I somehow have to first get the height of the div and then set it to that fixed height so the scrolling won't get messed up.

Is this an easy task? Like, can I just get the height of the div via jQuery and then set it to that height? Sounds pretty easy...

Comment: You might want to limit the number of GIF image elements that are displayed simultaneously in a view. i.e.: Remove image elements as they gone out of view while still keeping their `DIV` container, and readd them once the container go into view.